# Drawing a polyline on a grid using react three fiber

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I want to draw a polyline on a grid using react three fiber. The workflow would be as such:

1. Click on any of the grid cells (mousedown)
2. The start of the line is registered in the clicked cell
3. Move the mouse around: the line should follow the mouse cursor along the grid
4. Click on a second cell: the line segment should then be finished, and another line segment should start from there and so on

What I want to achieve is:

1. To draw a polyline. The breakpoints would be created as I click on the grid.
2. The line breakpoints should snap to the nearest grid vertex ie. the section where to nearest grid lines intersect

Is there a built-in method, a library or a simple approach that would allow me to achieve this?

Here's my `Grid`:

```
export const Grid = ({ children, scale, divisions = 10, ...props }) => {
  const grid = useRef();
  const plane = useRef();
  const [active, activate] = useState(false);
  useFrame((state, delta) => {
    easing.damp(grid.current.material, "opacity", active ? 1 : 0.9, 0.1, delta);
    easing.damp(
      plane.current.material,
      "opacity",
      active ? 1 : 0.25,
      0.1,
      delta
    );
  });
  return (
    <group {...props}>
      <group scale={scale}>
        <gridHelper ref={grid} args={[1, divisions, "#888", "#bbb"]} />
        <mesh receiveShadow ref={plane} rotation-x={-Math.PI / 2}>
          <planeGeometry />
          <meshStandardMaterial
            transparent
            color="lightblue"
            polygonOffset
            polygonOffsetUnits={1}
            polygonOffsetFactor={1}
          />
        </mesh>
      </group>
      <context.Provider value={activate}>{children}</context.Provider>
    </group>
  );
};
```